# Allowing HTML without attributes - secure?

Tags: php, xss

This function keeps html elements but removes attributes.

**Code:**

```
function clean( $html, $allowable_tags ) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( strip_tags( $html, $allowable_tags ), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );
    $xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $nodes = $xpath->query( '//@*' );
    foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
        $node->parentNode->removeAttribute( $node->nodeName );
    }
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

**Example:**

```
clean( "<u onclick='alert()'>test</u>", "<u>" );
```

**Output:**

```
<u>test</u>
```

**Question:**

What type of attacks could I expect whilst doing so?  I tested quite a few different things and it seems secure enough but, maybe there is something I am not considering that someone could do.

Comment: I'm not voting to close, largely because I'm not entirely sure, but I think that this sort of question is probably a better fit for [security.se], or maybe [webmasters.se]. It's certainly a valid question, but it's not really a specific programming problem.

Comment: This may be helpful http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @DeepakAdhikari Thank you but I am not entirely looking to use any outside resources. There are many, I know.

Comment: Stripping all attributes is certainly a secure way of going about things, and it seems to be secure enough (assuming you're blacklisting dangerous elements like `src` and `img`). You have to also consider inline <style> declarations, as a user could spoof elements of pages by overriding styles. You could take a look at the [XSS Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) for more information on giving your users a bit more flexibility while keeping the public markup in check.

Comment: @DavidThomas - I think you are right. I was thinking someone may see it and offer warnings of something like "a pitfall of strip tags is ___" or "the removeAttribute doesnt remove ___".